# Hide Repeating table programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, formatting, infopath2010

I have a label and a repeating table which is populated from a repeating field.

The field is assigned values (using InnerXML property) in code behind (getting from web service). So I want to hide the repeating table and the label as well in case there is no value available for the field.

1. Could I do it in the code behind?
2. Or how to do it using formatting rules? I have tried the rule with RepeatingField is blank but no luck.

**UPDATE:**

- Screenshot from the table:
  [image: Repeating table]
- Code behind from the form to populate data:

  ```
  string xmlString = String.Empty;
  foreach (var record in records)
  {
      xmlString += CreateGroup("StatementList");
      xmlString += CreateElement("Statement_ID", record.ID
      xmlString += CreateElement("Statement_Label", record.Label
      xmlString += CreateElement("Statement_Text", record.Text
      xmlString += EndGroup("StatementList");
  }

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(statementXML))
  {
      XPathNavigator nodeStatement = Root.SelectSingleNode("/my:AuditForm/my:MasterData/my:StatementGroup", NamespaceManager);
      nodeStatement.InnerXml = statementXML;
  }
  ```

Comment: can you use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: @Juventus18 I'm afraid you can't. It's is InfoPath from using XML structure and C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below steps for hiding the object in Infopath

If you need to hide Reapting table and lable in infopath then do as follow

```
Click on Reapting Section

Under Manage Rule Select Formatting

Add a condition as the label is blank

and check the check box for hide this control
```

If you need to hide label alone in infopath then do as follow

```
Click on that label

Under Manage Rule Select Formatting

Add a condition as the label is blank

and check the check box for hide this control
```

Comment: You miss the main point. I want to hide it ONLY WHEN there is no data in the repeating table.

Comment: can i get any screen shot of your form

Comment: @Shinigamae any screen shoot available

Comment: here you go. Updated.

Comment: have you tried the above 1st one that is `label is blank hide this control` @Shinigamae

Comment: did you mean the repeating table when you said 'label'? I have tried it.

Comment: What solution getting form that

Comment: I don't understand your question. I have tried using the rule if the repeating field is blank to hide the control but failed. I said it in the question already.

Comment: K label is inside the repeating table correct then if label is empty its called as repeating table is also empty.

Comment: it doesn't work. I assume it is because I generate the content of repeating table programmatically so it doesn't update the rule. I have set the rule to hide the repeating table when Statement_Label is blank. Am I doing it right?